# Disable Schema Validation for Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using Cosmos DB in Azure. I recently changed the schema to add more information. However, I'm confused because Cosmos uses SQL to query the database. Further, it seems I can't query based on the new schema because I receive the following error messsage:

```
 Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":22,"end":29},"code":"SC2001","message":"Identifier 'comment' could not be resolved."}]}
```

So I'm wondering is it possible to disable schema validation so I can query on the new `comment` attribute, without getting this error message.

Further, I'm confused how Cosmos DB can be considered a NoSQL database if it behaves much the same as MySQL.

Edit: The query I am using is

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE comment = ""
```

Comment: Can you share which is the query you are attempting to execute? It looks like the error is not the schema but how the query is written

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I have added the query I am using

Comment: FYI your error is a typo (you need `c.comment` and not `comment`). As for your comparison of Cosmos DB to MySQL, and how Cosmos DB could be considered "NoSQL" - NoSQL has nothing to do with a specific query language. It's about non-relational data modeling (and even within that definition, there are many types of NoSQL databases, and then many "brands" of each type of database). NoSQL is an umbrella term for a category of databases. One last thing: Cosmos DB does not behave the same way as MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to the schema, the error is saying your query is incorrectly written.

Following the official documentation (for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-getting-started#query-the-json-items)

The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c.comment = ""
```

Keep in mind that that query is not checking for documents that do not have the `comment` property, it's basically filtering documents that do have the `comment` property with an empty string value.

Comment: wow, that's embarrassing. thanks

Comment: Nothing embarrassing in asking for help.